# Почему из одного приложения нельзя работать с сетью в двух потоках?

Tags: java, android, http, сокет, service

Здравствуйте.Есть `Service` в нем есть коннект по сокету.Еще есть 4 activity класса из которых я делаю `post` запросы.Из-за того что `Socket` всегда держит связь, не получается отправлять запросы по `http`.Или все таки можно? у меня приложение виснет и `ProgressBar` вечно крутиться(это для http запроса).А отключение и включение `Service` корректно не работает.Вопрос можно ли в одном приложении одновременно держать подключенный `Socket` и и в то же время делать `http` запрос?

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MYSETTINGS",MODE_PRIVATE);
        login = sharedPreferences.getString("login2","");
        password = sharedPreferences.getString("password2","");
        if(!login.equals("")&&!password.equals("")){
            new MyAsyncTask().execute();
        }
        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        Intent restartService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                this.getClass());
        restartService.setPackage(getPackageName());
        PendingIntent restartServicePI = PendingIntent.getService(
                getApplicationContext(), 1, restartService,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmService.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 2000, restartServicePI);
        onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
        Log.e("onDestroyed","onDestroyed");
    }

class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
        String line = null;
        String line2 = null;

        Socket socket = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;
        int myFlag;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
               //тут вечный цикл , в котором соединение с сокетом
       }
}
```

Comment: Покажите, как вы в Service поток создаёте.

Comment: @Suvitruf  Код добавил.

Comment: `AsyncTask` не предназначен для таких вещей.

Comment: обычный Thread не работает как должен.Я хотел показывать Toast,Notification в runOnUiThread но он не срабатывает.Связи с этим сделал все в AsyncTask.

Comment: Но `socket` и `http` разные протоколы. Зачем вам слать `http` если вы, используете `socket` ?

Comment: @And на сокете было много логики.хотел по http чтоб на сокетах было меньше кода.

Comment: У Вас ужасный сервис - при любой попытке обращения к нему (в том числе и `stopService`) он плодит экземпляры `MyAsyncTask` и в каждом, соответственно, по вечному сокету.